# htaccess - Create a redirect that removes the "index.php" and link parameters[Solved]

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I would like to create a redirect of a link with parameters to remove the parameters and the index.php.

The link that is accessed from another website, so when you click on the link it automatically redirects without the parameters and without the index.php.

The url is:

```
https://www.example.org/reserve/folder_a/index.php?id=12345
```

to

```
https://www.example.org/reserve/folder_a/
```

At first, I want it that way, let's say url friendly, since the parameters are saved in a session variable, although I don't know if it will give just time when the redirection is done.

Currently if I delete all the content that appears after "folder_a" the page loads perfectly.

____EDIT_____

In the end I solved it with javascript:

```
window.location.href = url_base;
```

My url_base being the full path without index.php and without the parameters.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using core php or any framework for your project?

Comment: Not, This project uses core php.